# Compare value against previous value for different column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

What is the simplest way to compare one column against the previous value of another column, for each person - ideally without apply/lambda? In this example, "applez" vs "applet"

```
df     A         B      person
0    fruit    applet     abby
1    applez   cherry     abby
...
```

```
df.groupby("person").A.eq(df.groupby("person").B.shift())
```

Expected Output

```
0  NaN
1  False
```

Comment: `df['A'] == df.groupby("person").B.shift()`.

Comment: This doesn't work